# SQL Developer showing a weird data format in output

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to run a simple query which shows a weird date output format. When i try to run the below query, I get no value as output.

```
select value from SYS.nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_date_format';
```

please help.

Answer (score 3):

See the difference? Your query first, mine second.

```
SQL> select value from SYS.nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_date_format';

no rows selected

SQL> select value from SYS.nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR

SQL>
```

Parameters' names are UPPERCASE, e.g.

```
SQL> select parameter from nls_database_parameters where rownum < 5;

PARAMETER
------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE
NLS_TERRITORY
NLS_CURRENCY
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Littlefoot.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that - on Stack Overflow - "thank you" is expressed by accepting / upvoting helpful answers.